# increasing font size continuously

Tags: objective-c, font-size

How can I increase the font size of UILabel/UITextView/... continuously when I hold a button

I have a: `@property(nonatomic) CGFloat fontSize;` initialized to 17 in `ViewDidLoad`

This function is being called when the button is clicked:

```
- (IBAction)increaseFontSize:(id)sender {
    [self.label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:self.fontSize++]];
    NSLog(@"FONT SIZE: %f", self.fontSize);
}
```

So what I need is to increase the font continuously when I hold on the button, I think I should call the `increaseFontSize:` method repeatedly somehow

Comment: I suspect you have to set up a timer on touchDown, and then increment on timer ticks until touchUp.

Comment: You are using .xib or not?

Comment: no i'm using .storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two lines in `ViewDidLoad:`

```
 [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionStart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionEnd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And the Write this

```
-(IBAction) ActionEnd:(id)sender{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}
-(IBAction) ActionStart:(id)sender{
    myTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(increaseSize) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)increaseSize{
    self.fontSize = self.fontSize + 1.0;
    [self.label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:self.fontSize]];
}
```

Try this .
it will work.

Comment: This should work, but i think the first method should be -(IBAction) ActionEnd:(id)sender

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use the post-increment operator; that is for integers only.
2. You need to store the current font size so it increases next iteration:

Voilà:

```
- (IBAction)increaseFontSize:(id)sender
{
    self.fontSize = self.fontSize + 1.0;
    [self.label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:self.fontSize]];
    NSLog(@"FONT SIZE: %f", self.fontSize);
}
```

Comment: True, but that doesn't increase the font repeatedly if I hold the button

Comment: @AlexyIbrahim Yes it does.

Comment: Font size is increasing.. Perfect logic. only need change in button event select.

Answer (score 0):

Logic is perfect in above answer.

Just set Button Event to "Touch Drag Inside".

[image: Button Event]

It's working in my test application according to my understanding.

Thanks.